# Get MAX() for each row COUNT() MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have next 2 tables:

table querys and table time:

```
id | text     id | mid | country
1    hello     1    1       UK
2     hi       2    1       PL
3     sd       3    2       USA
```

id = mid, countries are different (UK, USA and so on).

I need to make next list:

```
UK - text 30 rows (this text has most mid in table 2 for UK)
USA - text 25 rows
PL - text 10 rows
...
SS - text 1 rows.
```

For now i have next idea:
Get which MID for each country has max rows and get text by mid=id and sort it.

```
SELECT time.country,querys.text,COUNT(mid) AS cnt 
     FROM time INNER JOIN `querys` ON(time.mid = querys.id) 
      GROUP BY mid 
      ORDER BY country,cnt
      DESC
```

But with this code i recieve all text with count of it.
Such as

```
UK text1 30, 
UK text2 25, 
PL text2 10, 
PL text3 5 ..
```

But i need only one max for each country, could anyone help how to cut the query to 1 max text for each country?

Comment: i was wondering why did you get such results? can you give sample records that match with your desired result? giving such current example will make the question confusing. perhps you can build it on http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6182/1/0 , now i see that it doesn't work correctly, but the main question is on :|

Comment: based on the records of the fiddle, what is your desired output then?

Comment: UA sdf 10, USA qw 2, and next countries if other will be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.country, 
        b.text, 
        COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM    time a
        INNER JOIN querys b
            ON a.mid = b.id
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Country, 
                    MAX(totalCount) max_count
            FROM
                    (
                        SELECT  Country, Mid, 
                        COUNT(*) totalCount
                        FROM    time
                        GROUP   BY Country, Mid
                    ) s
            GROUP   BY Country
        ) c ON a.country = c.country
GROUP   BY a.country, b.text, c.max_count
HAVING  COUNT(*) = c.max_count
ORDER   BY cnt DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6182/8)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦══════╦═════╗
║ COUNTRY ║ TEXT ║ CNT ║
╠═════════╬══════╬═════╣
║ UA      ║ sdf  ║  10 ║
║ USA     ║ qw   ║   2 ║
╚═════════╩══════╩═════╝
```

Comment: yeeeess! Thank you so much, it is exactly what i needed! Now i see how far i was from answer..

Comment: i'm a little bit dizzy this week. so for now it's the least answer i can give `:)` anyway, you're welcome!